# Sort a list in Visual Force Page

Tags: visual

I have a MVC aspx code where we create a two lists. And the list (!Templates and !items )  are diplayed in a visual force page.

Could someone help how to sort these list in an ascending alphabetical order?

```
 <apex:page controller="Project_Creation_Controller"
 tabStyle="MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c" >
     <style>
     body .bPageBlock .pbBody .dataCol
         {
         width: 100% !important;
         }
     </style>
     <apex:form >
         <apex:outputpanel >
             <apex:actionstatus id="message">
                 <apex:facet name="start">
                     <div class="waitingSearchDiv" id="el_loading" style="background-color:
 #DCD6D6;height:100%;opacity:0.65;width:100%;position:fixed;"> 
                         <div class="waitingHolder" style="top:120.2px; width: 91px;">
                             <img class="waitingImage" src="{!$Resource.loading}" title="Please Wait..." />
                             <span class="waitingDescription">Saving...</span>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </apex:facet>
             </apex:actionstatus>
         </apex:outputpanel>
         <apex:pageBlock >
             <apex:pageMessages id="pagemessages" ></apex:pageMessages>
             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Project Section" >
                 <apex:inputField value="{!projectObject.name}" /><br/>
                 <apex:outputField value="{!projectObject.DeadLine__c}"/>
             </apex:pageBlockSection>https://cs27.salesforce.com/_ui/common/apex/debug/ApexCSIPage#
             </apex:pageBlock>
         <apex:pageBlock id="templateBlock" >
             <apex:outputLabel value="Templates"></apex:outputLabel><br/>
             <apex:selectRadio value="{!templateName}" layout="pageDirection">
                 <apex:selectOptions value="{!Templates}" />
             </apex:selectRadio>

             <apex:outputLabel value="IT Templates"></apex:outputLabel><br/>
             <apex:selectRadio value="{!ITtemplateName}" layout="pageDirection" >
                 <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"  />
             </apex:selectRadio>

             <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                 <apex:commandButton value="Create Project" action="{!createProject}" status="message"
 reRender="pagemessages,template,pagemessages" />
                 <apex:commandButton value="Refresh" action="{!refresh}" />
             </apex:pageBlockButtons>
         </apex:pageBlock>
     </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

SOQL -

````
```apex
     Template__c templateobj = [select id,name,IT_Predecessor__c,IT_Task_Index__c,Active__c,Total_Duration__c from Template__c where id =: templateName];

                projectObject.IT_Predecessor__c=templateobj.IT_Predecessor__c;
                projectObject.IT_Task_Index__c=templateobj.IT_Task_Index__c;

                for(Project_Template_Task__c Taskobj : [select id,Assigned_User__c,Project_Template__r.Total_Duration__c,Day__c,Name,Task_Name__c,Assigned_To__c,Project_Template__r.name,Type__c,Project_Template__c,Index__c,Priority__c,Predecessors__c,
                                                        IT_Task__c,Description__c,Assigned_in_Jira__c,Planned_Duration__c,Parent_Template_Tasks__c, Notes_Required__c,Documents_Rquired__c,Approval_Required__c,Database_Import_Type__c,Database_Script_Name__c,Database_Target_Table__c,
                                                        (select id,Assigned_in_Jira__c,Assigned_User__c,Project_Template__r.Total_Duration__c,Day__c,Name,Task_Name__c,Assigned_To__c,Project_Template__r.name,Type__c,Project_Template__c,Index__c,Priority__c,Predecessors__c,
                                                         IT_Task__c,Description__c,Planned_Duration__c,Parent_Template_Tasks__c, Notes_Required__c,Documents_Rquired__c,Approval_Required__c,Database_Import_Type__c,Database_Script_Name__c,Database_Target_Table__c 
                                                         from Parent_Template_Tasks__r where Type__c='Sub-task' order by Index__c) from Project_Template_Task__c where (Project_Template__c =:templateName or Project_Template__c =:ITtemplateName) and (Type__c='Task' or Type__c='File Sub-Task')])
````

Comment: Why do you link to test.com? Are you using apex to retrieve the data? In that case adding the sort order on your query would be the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks Kasper. I  just changed it to test.com for security reasons. It is a production link in place. Yes I am using Apex code to retrieve the data . I  tried the sort in the soql query with no luck as the list that is being pulled is dynamic and I was not able to achieve the sort there, Thats is why I went this route.

Comment: Is the test.com link part of the question?

Comment: No test.com is not part of the question. Sorry.

Comment: Could you include the apex query in your question, and a bit more of the visualforce code?

Comment: Please use the `{}` tool in the editor to handle code formatting, or add three backticks before and after the code block. This ensures that SE renders your code and XML markup as code blocks. (Fixed here).

Comment: @DavidReed Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily sort lists in apex using `list.sort()`:

> The List.sort method sorts SelectOption elements in ascending order using the value and label fields, and is based on this comparison sequence.

know more about it here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_lists_sorting.htm

In case you are getting data from one of the salesforce objects then it is best to sort in the query:

```
SELECT <FIELDS>
FROM sObject
ORDER BY <FIELD> {ASC|DESC} NULLS {FIRST|LAST}
```

hope this helps!!